# Ошибка Laravel при подключении к БД

Tags: laravel

[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]:

Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

метод из коробки: app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено: Нужно добавить в метод boot(), в :

```
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

А также не забыть импортировать БД:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка появляется на версиях MySQL 5.6.
Еще одним вариантом решения может быть смена кодировки в `database.php`

```
'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8_general_ci'),
```